# How to include a date on the agenda for one day fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCDbQ.png)

I want this look when I switch to viewing the "agenda one day".
What i'm need to configure in the configuration for this view.

UPD: version 3.9

UPD2:

[sandbox there](https://codesandbox.io/s/ol20o02xn5)

this config file (short version):

```
const config = {
  header: false,
  schedulerLicenseKey: "GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source",
  defaultView: "agendaOneDay",
  slotDuration: "00:15:00",
  columnFormat: "ddd, DD MMM",
  editable: false,
  selectable: true,
  groupByResource: true,
  views: {
    agendaOneDay: {
      type: "agenda",
      duration: { days: 1 },
      buttonText: "1"
    },
    agendaThreeDay: {
      type: "agenda",
      duration: { days: 3 },
      buttonText: "3"
    }
  },
  resources: [
    { id: 5128, title: "Test title 1", eventColor: "#5eb15e" }
  ],
  events: [
    {
      start: "2018-09-24T09:00:00.000Z",
      end: "2018-09-24T09:30:00.000Z",
      resourceId: 5128,
      title: "test 1",
      event: {},
      color: "",
      textColor: "#191919"
    },
    {
      start: "2018-09-26T09:00:00.000Z",
      end: "2018-09-26T09:30:00.000Z",
      resourceId: 5128,
      title: "test 1",
      event: {},
      color: "",
      textColor: "#191919"
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: can you provide your code?  You have put full calendar versions 2 and 3.  Which one are you using?

Comment: You could use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/columnHeaderFormat depending on your exact requirement. Check the docs to see which version of fullCalendar you can use these options with.

Comment: @karen, 3.9.0 version

Comment: @ADyson, i'm check all this options, when calendar view switched to 'agenda' with duration days: 3, that ok, when duration days set to 1, title with date didn't show

Comment: please show us your exact code, thankyou.

Comment: @ADyson, https://codesandbox.io/s/ol20o02xn5?module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js

Comment: No, please add it to the question directly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . If your question doesn't include enough code to reproduce the issue then it can be closed as off-topic. This is because questions are supposed to help readers in the future, not just you. If your external sandbox link changes or disappears (which is outside StackOverflow's control) then your question becomes useless for other readers. A sandbox is nice to allow us to visualise the issue, but does not substitute for code shown here. Thankyou.

Comment: Thanks. So I see you're using Scheduler with a grouped agenda view. That makes a difference. Let me think about it.

Comment: Also...is there any specific reason you are not using the standard fullCalendar header?

Comment: @ADyson, need `groupByResource`, and plugin `scheduler`

Comment: See, if you use the normal header then you can easily set the "title" to provide what you need: https://codesandbox.io/s/84lj1nrv52

Comment: @ADyson, I'm use this for mobile SPA, and I need what was like a 3 day view, it does not take up much space on the screen

Comment: you can shrink the size of the header using CSS so it's no taller than your existing custom buttons. See the updated version: https://codesandbox.io/s/84lj1nrv52

Comment: P.S. I do not know why fullCalendar hides the column title in 1-day resource-grouped agenda mode, and why setting `columnHeader: true` does not restore it. I would have expected that it would work. And I don't know if it's intentional. Perhaps you can raise a bug.

Comment: @ADyson, i'm find in Scheduler this code:
`ResourceDayTableMixin.prototype.renderHeadTrHtml = function () {
        if (this.daysPerRow > 1) {
            if (this.datesAboveResources) {...} else {...}
        } else {...}
    };`
and switch in if block 1 to 0, and I got what I wanted

Comment: I am not the author of the source code and I'm not familiar with it, so I can't help you with that. If you can fix this so that it does what you want (as an option when columnHeader is true, maybe), then I'd suggest submitting a pull request to fullCalendar to get it incorporated in the next version.